# How to fix race condition between Promise resolving on win.loadFile() and app.on('browser-window-created') event

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am working on an Electron app, where one module creates a `BrowserWindow` and other modules (all of them in the main process) can access the window *after* it has been fully loaded (including situations where the window has been closed in the meantime).

I'm working with Electron 5.0.0 on macOS.

Here is a simplified version of what I've come up with, so far:

```js
// module mainWindow.js

const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
let ready = null

const createWindow = () => {
  console.log('creating window')  
  return new Promise((resolve) => {  
    let win = new BrowserWindow({
      show: false,
    })
    win.on('closed', () => {
      ready = null
    })
    win.loadFile('renderer.html').then(() => {
      win.show()
      resolve(win)
      console.log('window.load resolved')    
    })
    console.log('window id', win.id)        
}

const get = (create) => {
  console.log('get')
  if (ready) {
    console.log('ready')
    return ready
  } else {
    console.log('not ready')
    if (create) {
      console.log('creating')
      ready = createWindow()
      return ready
    } else {
      console.log('rejecting')
      return Promise.reject()
    }
  }
}

exports.get = get


// some other module

const win = require('mainWindow.js')
win.get(true).then((win) => { /* ... */ })


// yet another module

const { app } = require('electron')
const win = require('mainWindow.js')
app.on('browser-window-created', () => {
  console.log('app.browser-window-created')
  win.get(false).then((win) => {
    log('got it')
    // ...
  }, () => {
    log('there is no window')
  })
})
```

The way I see it,`createWindow()` should return a unresolved promise (which then gets stored in `ready`) *before* asynchronously creating the window. But my console reads:

```sh
get
not ready
creating
creating window
app.browser-window-created
get
not ready
rejecting
window id 1
there is no window
window.load resolved
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the event is triggered synchronously, therefore it runs before the function finished executing, and `ready =` did not yet run. To resolve that, you have to defer the window creation:

```
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   setTimeout(() => {
     //...
   });
  });
```

You could also defer that using another promise when assigning to `ready` inside `get`:

```
  ready = Promise.resolve().then(createWindow);
```

Alternatively you could reassign `ready` before creating the window, for that you have to expose `resolve` from the callback:

```
  let resolve;
  ready = new Promise(it => resolve = it);

  // create window ...
  // somewhen ...
  resolve(win);
```

Comment: Thanks! I spent hours trying to figure that one out (your second solution works like a charm for me).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that
`let win = new BrowserWindow` immediately triggers `'browser-window-created'` event, thus in its callback you don't find any pending Promise.

So I suggest you to restructure the code.

For example [`app.on('browser-window-created')`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#event-browser-window-created) can be used to obtain the created BrowserWindow. Adding listener to `'did-finish-load'` of BrowserWindow's webContents you simply get *exactly* the same callback as you would with the returned Promise ([loadFile](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#winloadfilefilepath-options) resolves for that event)

```
app.on('browser-window-created', (event, window) => {
  console.log('app.browser-window-created')
  window.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    console.log('got it')
    // ...
  })
  window.webContents.on('did-fail-load', () => {
    console.log('there is no window')
  })
})
```